# How to log arduino data using pyserial and gspread only once to google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, arduino, pyserial, gspread

I'm teaching myself to code (in the early stages) and I'm trying to log serial data from an arduino to google sheets using pyserial and gspread.  Data from the arduino is intermittent (0-10 entries a minute roughly) but so far I can only log the first entry repeatedly.

I get that it's doing this because it's looping but I don't know how to fix it.  If I were logging to a txt or csv file I could close and reopen the log file but I'm not sure if that makes sense to do with google sheets or how to do it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what might be a good way to log each entry only once?  Here's the basic meat of my code.

Please remember I'm a novice!

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("meditation_logger").sheet1
wks.resize(1)

data = ser.readline().strip()
date = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%y")
time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
dataToAdd = [date, time, data]

while True:
    wks = gc.open("meditation_logger").sheet1
    if data:
        print data, date, time
        wks.append_row(dataToAdd)
```

Comment: You are only reading the first line of your serial data here: `data = ser.readline().strip()`. You will have to call it again to read the second line and so forth. So move that line and `dataToAdd = [date, time, data]` into the while loop.

Comment: Ahh!  Of course.  Thank you.  That makes complete sense.  Much appreciated!  :-)   Worked like a charm.